# MATLABs fill in PyPlot

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

In MATLAB, filled polygons can be plotted with colors defined in the nodes using the `fill` command as (example with 2 triangles):

```
x = [0 1 1; 0 1 0]';
y = [0 0 1; 0 1 1]';
z = [0 1 2; 0 2 3]';

fill(x,y,z)
```

Is there an equivalent command, or another convenient way, to do the same in `matplotlib`?

Comment: How about [`matplotlib.patches.Polygon`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html?highlight=patches.polygon#matplotlib.patches.Polygon)? See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935701/ploting-filled-polygons-in-python)

Comment: I saw, that question. However, as I understand it that function plots the whole polygon in the same color? In MATLAB it is possible to specify the colors of the corners, so that the color inbetween is a gradient, as in the example.

Comment: So what are your real data actually like? I only found `matplotlib.imshow` that can do interpolation inside your faces, but that assumes a rectangular grid as `x` and `y`...

Comment: Basically I have elements in a mesh (in this case triangles) with nodal values. Much like the example above. It is possible to convert the data to coordinate data for each node (say in vectors `X,Y`) with nodal values in a vector `Z`.  Maybe this can be plotted more easily? It is not necessary to plot the actual elements.

Comment: Very much so. If `x` and `y` are on a mesh, as in `x,y=numpy.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)`, and `z` is again defined on that mesh, possibly as a function of `x` and `y`, then `matplotlib.imshow(z,interpolation='bilinear',extent=...` will do something very similar. But you need an equidistant grid, since [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow) is designed for plotting images, and interprets your data as pixels (and might flip the coordinate axes). I couldn't find another function capable of intrafacet interpolation, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that my points are more or less randomly distributed in space. So definitely not in an equidistant meshgrid. I worked around my problem by calling `MATLAB` and using its `fill` function, but this is not optimal in any way.

Comment: Your problem sounds ideal to me for use with [`plot_trisurf`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots) as that will do the triangulation for you, however that also can't interpolate inside facets.

Comment: I might have found what you're looking for. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836199/interpolating-a-3d-surface-known-by-its-corner-nodes-and-coloring-it-with-a-colo) has an accepted answer telling you that `shading interp` is not available in python, and the second (low-voted, bountied) answer will show you how to use `tri.LinearTriInterpolator` with `plot_trisurf` to refine your mesh:) So far this sounds best to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a solution based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836199/interpolating-a-3d-surface-known-by-its-corner-nodes-and-coloring-it-with-a-colo) and the answers therein. It seems that intrafacet interpolation is not built into `pyplot`, so you need a workaround by creating a finer interpolating mesh on your data.

Using your example data in MATLAB:

```
x = [0 1 1; 0 1 0]';
y = [0 0 1; 0 1 1]';
z = [0 1 2; 0 2 3]';

fill(x,y,z);
```

produces this plot (which will be a control for us):
[image: matlabfill_control]

First you have to determine how your data are represented in `python`. The natural inputs to the functions I'm going to use are 1d arrays, so you might throw away the multiplicities in your data. If you don't actually care for the triangles, but only the `z` landscape, then you can let `python` do the triangulation for you:

```
from matplotlib import tri, cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[0, 1, 1, 0]
y=[0, 0, 1, 1]
z=[0, 1, 2, 3]

triang=tri.Triangulation(x,y) #Delaunay triangulation of input
refiner=tri.UniformTriRefiner(triang)
interp=tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang,z) #linear interpolator
new,new_z=refiner.refine_field(z,interp,subdiv=6) #refined mesh; uses 4**subdiv!

fig = plt.figure()
plt.tripcolor(new.x,new.y,new_z,cmap=cm.jet)
```

The result:
[image: python, automatic triangulation]

You can see that the result is different from the control, because `matplotlib` chose another triangulation as we did in MATLAB. If your triangles are small, and you only need a smooth figure, then this should suffice.

However, it is possible to provide the triangulation manually. It would be less then trivial to convert your MATLAB input to a format that is palatable by `python`, so it's up to how desperate you are. For our small example I can choose the triangles manually:

```
x=[0, 1, 1, 0]
y=[0, 0, 1, 1]
z=[0, 1, 2, 3]
tridat=[[0,3,2],[0,2,1]] # 2 triangles in counterclockwise order

triang=tri.Triangulation(x,y,tridat) #this has changed
refiner=tri.UniformTriRefiner(triang)
interp=tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triang,z) #linear interpolator
new,new_z=refiner.refine_field(z,interp,subdiv=6) #refined mesh

fig = plt.figure()
plt.tripcolor(new.x,new.y,new_z,cmap=cm.jet)
```

Result:
[image: python manual triangulation]

This is clearly comparable to the MATLAB version. For a smoother interpolation you can increase `subdiv` in the code, but do so carefully: each triangle is split into `4^subdiv` parts, so the memory need of plotting grows *very* rapidly with this parameter.

Comment: Looks great! Well done sir. This time I ended up using another solution by will definitely look into this one the next time.

Comment: @kirderf thank you, this approach is far from efficient, so you're probably better off with the other solution you found:)